# Is it possible to show a Picker permanently in a Form in SwiftUI?

Tags: forms, swiftui, picker

I have a simple question for Pickers in Forms and Sections: Is it possible to show a Picker permanently in the WheelPickerStyle in this construct?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
           Form {
                Section {
                  DatePicker(selection:.constant(Date()), label: { Text("") })
                }.pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
           }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it should be

```
Form {
     Section {
        DatePicker(selection:.constant(Date()), label: { Text("") })
            .datePickerStyle(WheelDatePickerStyle())
     }
}
```

or in variant with tracking state:

```
    @State private var date = Date()
    var body: some View {
       Form {
         Section {
           DatePicker(selection:$date, label: { Text("") })
                .datePickerStyle(WheelDatePickerStyle())
         }
       }
    }
```